# How to check for cloud-code generated errors on parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

My app is running on parse.com and all the cloudcode errors have code 141.

When I'm running a certain function, in some rare cases I get this exception trown by the cloudcode: `Error: User isn't in the database. (Code: 141, Version: 1.2.19)`

However, when I'm trying to segue the user back to the home screen with this code, nothing gets called:

```
if(error){
   NSLog(@"Error logged: %@", error); //loggs: Error logged refreshtokencoinbase: Error Domain=Parse Code=141 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 141.)" UserInfo=0x10ae0e460 {error=User isn't in the database., code=141}

   if([error  isEqual:@"User isn't in the database." ]){
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"moveToStart" sender:self];
   }
}
```

How do I handle cloudcode generated errors like this one?

Comment: What about comparing it to `error.userInfo[@"error"]`?

Comment: @knshn wheh that worked! Thanks so much! If you answer my question I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse errors have the description text in `error.userInfo[@"error"]`. It may not be a good idea to check the error type by the text, but here you have no other chance.